# Creating your own ca with open ssl in windows

Tags: openssl, certificate

A question I have is that, when a certificate is signed by a ca what actually happens. Does the ca use his private key to hash  or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CA sets the content of the X.509 certificate (see [`TBScertificate` sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)), including its own Subject DN as the certificate Issuer DN (same for alternative names, if any).

Then, it signs the certificate to form the `Certificate` sequence: it sets the signature type and fills in the signature which it has produced using its private key. For example, if the signature type is SHA-1 with RSA (quite common), it will produce a SHA-1 hash/digest of `TBScertificate` and sign it using its (RSA) private key.

Comment: yeah got it. What happens if there is a chain of the certificates?

Comment: Each one signs the following one (the signer's Subject DN becomes the Issuer DN of the signed cert). You can then verify the signatures by using the public key of the issuer, in chain.

Comment: If I have certificate which has a chain length of 4 in my server keystore, then when the client requests for certificate only the root certificate will be sent right? or will all the four certificates be sent

Comment: The server should send all but the root CA cert. The point is that it must send at least its own certificate so that the client ca verify it.

Comment: So the client should contain the root certificate and the server should send al the certificate till the root certificates. I am using jboss server. Will this happen automatically. I know to change the server.xml and make it point to the keystore and all. But will the server automatically do the job of sending all the certificates but the root certificate.

Comment: If the chain was imported correctly in the keystore, yes, it should do it.